# How domain names are automatically assigned to instances in cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

Could anyone please explain how domain names are dynamically assigned to instances on cloud, for example, in AWS.

When you launch an instance in AWS, a domain name is assigned to it as ec2-aa-bb-0-94.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

I'd like to know how this is being done.

Answer (score 0):

AWS runs own DNS server. Whenever a new instance is created, a new record is inserted into the DNS. The long dns automatically resolved to ip in the domain.

a-54-39-254-23.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com will resolve to 54.39.254.23

Comment: My question is, how that new A record is inserted into the DNS sever. What kind of tool or automation would be used to do that.

Comment: They have Route53 product. They must be using Route53 as their DNS provider. They have API for Route53 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html

Comment: I can use Route 53 as a DNS service. But I want to know the internal working of Route53 itself. Like how it updates A records on the zone file when the instance is provisioned. I want to know internal working details

Comment: @AdaikalRaj Kunal just answered your question. It's done via scripted calls to the Route53 API. Go look at the API.

Comment: @MarkB I'm not trying to use Route53. I would like to know how instances get domain name automatically when you provision them. I said AWS as an example. You took take any other cloud too like azure, jelastic. At core, I believe these cloud providers would have USED PowerDNS / BIND9. I'd like to know how the zone files are updated when the instances are provisioned. Do they use any tool? Or they use configuration management tools like chef or puppet? Could you please guide me through any document? I'd like to set up own dns in our openstack environment. We don't want to use cloud dns service

Comment: You want to know how the zone files are updated when the instance is provisioned, and I'm telling you that Amazon has some code to call the Route53 API to provision a new DNS record when the instance is provisioned. Amazon has their own proprietary service built on top of AWS for this sort of thing.

Comment: I get that. Now, if I want to set up now my own DNS service like AWS Route53, what are the possibilites. OpenStack Desginate(one of the openstack services) does that but unfortunately it is still being built and not production ready. Do you know any automation tools to do that?. Or any API, I could make use of, from PowerDNS / Bind9?